# Should a off-grid wind charge controller be UL certified?

Tags: battery-charging, inverter, generator, solar-charge-controller

I recently bought a 2kW wind generator, 48V Charge controller and a UL certified off grid wind inverter for my Home based wind project prototype. My charge controller which I am using to rectify the AC output from the generator and to charge the batteries in not UL certified, but my inverter is UL certified. Is it safe to use it for the prototype? Any guidance is much appreciated.

P.s. I bought them via Alibaba

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83542/discussion-on-question-by-theelectrician-should-a-off-grid-wind-charge-controlle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all products can be or have to be, listed. For some products there are no applicable UL standards; for others, the products simply aren’t safe enough to ever be listed. like vinyl dryer hose.

Your Risks are your own;
- tornado and hurricane safety protection & tower/foundation installation.
- Lightning ground rod installation
- Battery overcharge verification testing
- design verification tests after installation (commissioning test)

Comment: Thanks @Tony EE rocketscientist. I really appreciate your guidance!

Comment: I would stick a vibration sensor on it and check balance for resonance effects at high wind speed.This requires some experience on spectrum of resonance and Q or gain at resonance if no guy wires or dampeners

Comment: Sure, that is a great advice! I will do that!